# Is this identify valid?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

$$\sin(t) \dot{}e^{if(t)} = \sin(t+f(t))$$
I've never seen this identify before but it follows directly from the relation between complex exponentials and the trigonometric functions.

Comment: If both $t$ and $f(t)$ are real, the real part of the left side is $\sin t \cos f(t)$ which doesn't match the right side.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly false. Take $f(t) = -t$. Then your would-be identity boils down to: $$\sin(t) e^{-it} = 0 \implies \sin(t) = 0,$$ which is valid for only some values of $t$. (Here I used that the exponential never vanishes)

Answer (score 0):

Not true.  Try $t = 0$, $f(t) = \pi/2$.